# Construct column and rows from list in Python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I have a list as follows:

```
A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS          COM NEW          000886309       39      6290   SH     SOLE            6290         0         0

A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS          COM NEW          000886309      156     25100   SH     DEFINED      2    25100         0         0

AAR CORP                          COM              000361105        7       305   SH     SOLE      6      305         0         0

ATMOS ENERGY CORP                 COM              049560105      186      6342   SH     SOLE            6342         0         0

CLEAR CHANNEL OUTDOOR HLDGS       CL A             18451C109        6       609   SH     SOLE      6      609         0         0
```

I am trying to transform above list to the following row by column format (where the first row contains the column titles):

```
 CUSIP         VALUE    SHARES DETAILS TYPE    MGRNO  SOLE        SHARED    OTHER
000886309       39      6290   SH     SOLE            6290         0         0
000886309      156     25100   SH     DEFINED   2    25100         0         0
000361105        7       305   SH     SOLE      6      305         0         0
049560105      186      6342   SH     SOLE            6342         0         0
18451C109        6       609   SH     SOLE      6      609         0         0
```

Although I have tried some codes to transform the list into a more organized way, I got stuck with handling this step of the code. Is there any way to transform such an unclassified list? As you can see, there are occasionally gaps in the first column (which is the name of the company) and the second column (which is the stock ticker), but then the data gets cleaner (i.e., columns 3 to the end). I do actually not need the first two column information (i.e., stock ticker and firm name), but everything else.

Could someone please provide some tips on how to handle such a data transformation? Thanks in advance for any tips / codes.

EDITED:

I thought that it would be helpful to provide the data (from a US government source) and the code to get to the part I am stuck at.

Link to the text file I am working with:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1364742/000108636410008916/blkinc.txt

Code:

```
def group_by_heading(some_source):
buffer= []
for line in some_source:
    if line.startswith( "<S>"):
        if buffer: yield buffer
        buffer= [line]
    elif line.startswith("</TABLE>"):
        break
    else: 
        buffer.append(line )
yield buffer



with open("/Users/MacBook/Desktop/SEC_DATA/13F/13F_BLK/0001086364-10-008916.txt", "r") as source:
    for heading_and_lines in group_by_heading( source ):
        heading= heading_and_lines[0]
        lines= heading_and_lines[1:]
```

Comment: it looks like it's fixed width... can we bet on that?  (as there is no delimiter)

Comment: Can you change your list to make more like a python variable for better understanding?

Comment: What format are you reading this in from?

Comment: I have just provided the link and code to obtain and manipulate the data. It is a SEC 13F-HR dataset, which is commonly used in the finance world. As to your question @RaoSahab and chrisz, would this be sufficient? Or should I change it and provide an example of the python variable?

Comment: Exactly, it does not. But there is a lot of information that is not needed so I deleted those information and left the parts that are needed. Would there be another way to extract the data into the format I would need @joefromct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the data into a string that looks like this (without any of the headers):

```
s = '''A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS          COM NEW          000886309       39      6290   SH     SOLE            6290         0         0
A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS          COM NEW          000886309      156     25100   SH     SOLE      2    25100         0         0
A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS          COM NEW          000886309        6       945   SH     SOLE      6      945         0         0
AAR CORP                          COM              000361105        7       305   SH     SOLE      6      305         0         0
AARONS INC                        COM              002535201      108      3892   SH     SOLE            3892         0         0
AARONS INC                        COM              002535201      316     11400   SH     SOLE      2    11400         0         0
AARONS INC                        COM              002535201      943     34019   SH     SOLE      6    34019         0         0'''
```

You can use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/getpandas.html) to read that into a DataFrame (I guessed at the column names):

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s{2,}',names=['issuer','title','cusip','val','prn amt','put-call','discr','mgrs','sole','shared','other'])
```

Which looks like this:

```
>>> print(df.head().to_string())
                     issuer    title      cusip  val  prn amt put-call discr  mgrs   sole  shared  other
0  A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS  COM NEW  000886309   39     6290       SH  SOLE  6290      0       0    NaN
1  A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS  COM NEW  000886309  156    25100       SH  SOLE     2  25100       0    0.0
2  A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS  COM NEW  000886309    6      945       SH  SOLE     6    945       0    0.0
3                  AAR CORP      COM  000361105    7      305       SH  SOLE     6    305       0    0.0
4                AARONS INC      COM  002535201  108     3892       SH  SOLE  3892      0       0    NaN
```

The columns can be rearranged/selected to your liking:

```
>>> df_2 = df[['cusip','val','prn amt','put-call','discr','sole','shared','other']]
>>> print(df_2.head().to_string())
       cusip  val  prn amt put-call discr   sole  shared  other
0  000886309   39     6290       SH  SOLE      0       0    NaN
1  000886309  156    25100       SH  SOLE  25100       0    0.0
2  000886309    6      945       SH  SOLE    945       0    0.0
3  000361105    7      305       SH  SOLE    305       0    0.0
4  002535201  108     3892       SH  SOLE      0       0    NaN
>>>
```

---

I didn't look past the first dozen lines or so to try and figure a delimiter/separator, unfortunately it wasn't tab delimited so I used multiple spaces and there was a caveat in [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) for regex separators and quoted data. If some of the data is *irregular* or columns are only separated by a single *space* then this will have problems.

`pandas.read_csv` has many [optional parameters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files) and maybe they can be used to deal with the errant lines - maybe the `error_bad_lines` parameter would help but it's description only deals with too many columns.

One option would be to pre-process the data but you would still need to figure out a strategy for splitting lines into columns and dealing with lines with too few or too many columns after the split.  Finding a specification for the data format might help along these lines.

This line, in the raw data, looks suspiciously like registration marks for columns (maybe there are only ten columns) ...

```
<S>                                                 <C>       <C>      <C>     <C>      <C>     <C>    <C>      <C>      <C>
```

---

Maybe the columns are fixed width. Pandas has a method to deal with that also [`pandas.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns).  Without trying to figure out the actual column widths letting Pandas *infer* them, the following works for the first 15 lines.

```
col_names=['CUSIP','VALUE','SHARES','DETAILS','TYPE','MGR NO','SOLE','SHARED','OTHER']
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(s), usecols=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],names=col_names)
```

`usecols` filters for the columns you are interested in.  You may also want to specify the data type for each column using the [`dtype` parameter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-column-data-types).

```
>>> print(df.head().to_string())

     CUSIP  VALUE  SHARES DETAILS  TYPE  MGR NO   SOLE  SHARED  OTHER
0   886309     39    6290      SH  SOLE     NaN   6290       0      0
1   886309    156   25100      SH  SOLE     2.0  25100       0      0
2   886309      6     945      SH  SOLE     6.0    945       0      0
3   361105      7     305      SH  SOLE     6.0    305       0      0
4  2535201    108    3892      SH  SOLE     NaN   3892       0      0
```

Comment: This is very helpful @wwii. I am getting, however, the following error:

    raise ParserError(msg)

ParserError: Expected 11 fields in line 6353, saw 12. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: Can we maybe use the following, instead of pd.read_csv:

items = [(rx.split(line)) for line in s .split("\n") if line]. I am not sure how to add the column names though.. Also, I have noticed that there is an issue with the number of items in a list. Whenever there is a missing OTHERMGRNOS (i.e., MGRNO) value, then the entire items are shifted when the data is combined. Is there a way to fix this? In other words, is it possible to add manually an item 7 for lists that have 10 items rather than 11 item (i.e., size is 10 rather than 11)?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but maybe this will help;

You have to anchor on something; I assumed that the first two columns were delimited by at least two-spaces, and then discarded them.  You can see this in the `re.split` bit in `process_a_row`.

After that, just split on spaces and you should get the good stuff.

I used `tabulate` to write the table, but you'll have to install a pip module for that... there should be a bunch of ways you could work with printing fixed width output.  Probably you would prefer at somepoint to work with the list of dictionaries anyway (that i printed out in the middle).

```
# input data
input_list = ["A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS          COM NEW          000886309       39      6290   SH     SOLE            6290         0         0",
              "",
              "A D C TELECOMMUNICATIONS          COM NEW          000886309      156     25100   SH     DEFINED      2    25100         0         0",
              "",
              "AAR CORP                          COM              000361105        7       305   SH     SOLE      6      305         0         0",
              "",
              "ATMOS ENERGY CORP                 COM              049560105      186      6342   SH     SOLE            6342         0         0",
              "",
              "CLEAR CHANNEL OUTDOOR HLDGS       CL A             18451C109        6       609   SH     SOLE      6      609         0         0",]

columns_i_want = ["SHARES",
                  "DETAILS",
                  "TYPE",
                  "MGRNO",
                  "SOLE",
                  "SHARED",
                  "OTHER"]
```

Here's one of many ways you could process the input:

```
import re

def process_a_row(row):
    _, _, good_data = re.split("\s{2,}", row ,maxsplit=2)
    return dict(zip(columns_i_want, good_data.split()))

new_rows = [process_a_row(r) for r in input_list if r != "" ]
print(new_rows)

In [50]:
[   {'SHARES': '000886309', 'DETAILS': '39', 'TYPE': '6290', 'MGRNO': 'SH', 'SOLE': 'SOLE', 'SHARED': '6290', 'OTHER': '0'},
    {'SHARES': '000886309', 'DETAILS': '156', 'TYPE': '25100', 'MGRNO': 'SH', 'SOLE': 'DEFINED', 'SHARED': '2', 'OTHER': '25100'},
    {'SHARES': '000361105', 'DETAILS': '7', 'TYPE': '305', 'MGRNO': 'SH', 'SOLE': 'SOLE', 'SHARED': '6', 'OTHER': '305'},
    {'SHARES': '049560105', 'DETAILS': '186', 'TYPE': '6342', 'MGRNO': 'SH', 'SOLE': 'SOLE', 'SHARED': '6342', 'OTHER': '0'},
    {'SHARES': '18451C109', 'DETAILS': '6', 'TYPE': '609', 'MGRNO': 'SH', 'SOLE': 'SOLE', 'SHARED': '6', 'OTHER': '609'}]


from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(new_rows, headers="keys"))

In [51]:
   SHARES       DETAILS    TYPE  MGRNO    SOLE       SHARED    OTHER
---------  ---------  ------  -------  -------  --------  -------
000886309         39    6290  SH       SOLE         6290        0
000886309        156   25100  SH       DEFINED         2    25100
000361105          7     305  SH       SOLE            6      305
049560105        186    6342  SH       SOLE         6342        0
18451C109          6     609  SH       SOLE            6      609
```

Comment: Thanks, @joefromct. I will give this a try now. I see what you are doing.

Comment: It's working quite well, @joefromct. After installing tabulate, the print command returned the output that is needed. Rather than printing the output, is there any way to assign the printed data to a type (with rows and columns) that can be exported to a CSV file?

Comment: One quick followup point, @joefromct. In your code, I have noticed that there is an issue with the number of items in a list. Whenever there is a missing MGRNO value (for example the first row), then the entire items are shifted to the left when the data is combined. Is there a way to fix this? In other words, is it possible to add manually an entry for MGRNO for lists that have 6 items rather than 7 item (i.e., size is 6 rather than 7)? Otherwise, the data is incorrectly specified (i.e., the columns will be mixed up).